# react-admin: Edit form not prefilled with existing attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I recently discovered [react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin). Everything seems fine but I ran into an issue I could not find any solution for:

When editing an **existing** record all input fields are empty. When submitting the empty form - all attributes get "nulled".

This is my code:

```
// src/users.js
export const UserEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit title="Edit User" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <DisabledInput label="Id" source="id" />
      <TextInput source="first_name" />
      <TextInput source="last_name" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);

// App.js
const restClient = jsonAPIRestClient("http://localhost:3000/admin");

const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={restClient}>
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} edit={UserEdit}/>
  </Admin>
);
```

For the data adapter I am using the `jsonAPIRestClient`. Records are all  stored and available in the redux store.

Whats kind of interesting: The Id which is a `DisabledInput` is showing up in the form.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "aor-jsonapi-client": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-admin": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
I just found out, that the users attributes are in the input fields of the edit page for ca. 1/10 of a second. Then the fields are cleared?!

**EDIT 3:**
Here is the redux action that leads to this Bug:

`RA/CRUD_GET_ONE_SUCCESS`
[image]

So I guess what's going wrong here is the data provider that stores the fetched single resource wrong in the redux store. Is this correct?

**EDIT 4:**
Unfortunately it seems that the data provider is bad. The repository seems to be unmaintained at the moment. There is a PR which aims at fixing this problem.

https://github.com/moonlight-labs/aor-jsonapi-client/pull/6

Comment: Hi, what version of react-admin are you using? It might be a bug, but I can help you filling an issue.
Mind you try to repeat your issue on this code sandbox please, and give me the link? https://codesandbox.io/s/olr88y53xy

Comment: @Kmaschta I updated the question and added my package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Alternative jsonapi client

I just found another, working react-admin jsonapi client, here:
https://github.com/henvo/ra-jsonapi-client

which can be installed with:

```
npm install ra-jsonapi-client
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using `aor-jsonapi-client`, a client for [Admin-On-Rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) which is the old version of [React Admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/).

In order to fix your issue, I would recommend to use a related data provider for React Admin like:

- [ra-data-json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-data-json-server)
- or, [ra-data-simple-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-data-simple-rest)

See the [documentation about data providers](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html) on React Admin for further informations.

Comment: Should this client then maybe removed from here: marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#available-providers

Comment: You're right, I opened a PR for that: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2300